# Cordova build : Error :Failed to run "java -version "

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I've installed the latest Apple update for Java, here is what the terminal now says:

```
$ java -version  
java version "1.8.0.0_25"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0.0_25-b18)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

After that I still have the following result:

```
$ cordova build
Running command...  

[Error: Failed to run "java - version ", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from htpp://...

[Error: ERROR : build one of the platforms : Eroor:C:\User\HelloWorld\paltforms\android\cordova\build.bat:Command faild with exit code 2...]
```

Looking around there seems to be huge confusion on how to activate Java. 
Do I now also need to download and install the Oracle Java package from the following link?[link](http://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp)

Comment: i try this :  %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the PATH variable. But it is not work.

Comment: look at the first line, the past obviously is set because otherwise you would not be able to call java. Did you have a look at the build.bat ? Where does cordova expect the java executable to be found ? Perhaps it is addressed directly and you used a different path. Just to be sure you should post the output of "echo %JAVA_HOME%". And you should check if you really have javac too

Comment: i first call java version. it is work. but if i  call cordova build , it is not work.  i  have the build.bat

Comment: yes, I can see that in your question

Comment: Can you post the content of the build.bat ?

Comment: @ECHO OFF
SET script_path="%~dp0build"
IF EXIST %script_path% (
        node %script_path% %*
   
) ELSE (
    ECHO.
    ECHO ERROR: Could not find 'build' script in 'cordova' folder, aborting...>&2
 
    EXIT /B 1
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your .bash_profile file...

`nano ~/.bash_profile`

Adding is line:

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: I do not have to .bash_profile. I created the  .bash_profile and  I did what you said. But it is not work .

Comment: You installed Android SDK?

Comment: i dont have android sdk. i installed android sdk after run :) thanks for everthing..

Answer (score 2):

Note that even if cordova/phonegap indicate `java -version`, it doesn't say that you need the JDK and not the JRE.

`java -version` returns the JRE version.

So you will have an answer for `java -version`, but you won't have the necessary JDK.

Install the Java JDK, and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i added

```
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin
```

to my enviroment variables and restarted my IDE.
The \bin folder is important
Be sure you added the JAVA_HOME Variable under your Userenviroment and not under the System.

Comment: Did you add this in the PATH environment variable?